# Why does JPA Criteria Query not allow to correlate a subquery?

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.0

I need to match the main query with a subquery with the ID of category. JPA Criteria Query does not allow me to set the Predicate to the Category because the query is returning types `PubThread`.

```
Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
```

Below the entire criteria query.

```
   CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<PubThread> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PubThread.class);

    // 1) MainQuery
    // Create the FROM
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThread = cq.from(PubThread.class);
    // Create the JOIN from the first select: join-chaining. You only need the return for ordering. e.g. cq.orderBy(cb.asc(categoryJoin.get(Pub_.title)));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoin = rootPubThread.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    // Create the WHERE
    cq.where(criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)));
    // Create the SELECT, at last
    cq.select(rootPubThread).distinct(true);

    // 2) Subquery
    Subquery<PubThread> subquery = cq.subquery(PubThread.class); 
    Root<PubThread> rootPubThreadSub = subquery.from(PubThread.class); 
    subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId));
    Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoinSub = rootPubThreadSub.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
    subquery.select(rootPubThreadSub);

    Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
    subquery.where(correlatePredicate);
    cq.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));
```

How do you formulate this Criteria Query to match this SQL code? I think I'm pretty close.

```
SELECT Distinct(pt2.id), pt2.name
FROM pubthread pt2
JOIN pub_pubthread ppt2 ON pt2.id = ppt2.pubThreads_id
JOIN pub p2 ON ppt2.pups_id = p2.id
JOIN pubcategory pc2 ON p2.pubCategoryId = pc2.id
WHERE pt2.id != 1 and EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT(pt.id) FROM pubthread pt
    JOIN pub_pubthread ppt ON pt.id = ppt.pubThreads_id
    JOIN pub p ON ppt.pups_id = p.id
    JOIN pubcategory pc ON p.pubCategoryId = pc.id
    where pc2.id = pc.id and pt.id = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned the wrong object to the predicate. If you want to match a subquery's id to the parent id, you must assign the `Join`, not the `Root`, if predicates do not belong to the root. Well, how obvious is that. :) However, glad to share. Below is the new query. There is an additional `Predicate` at the very bottom, which solves the issue. Also in conjunction with another boolean statement.

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery mainQuery = criteriaBuilder
                .createQuery(PubThread.class);

```
// 1) MainQuery
// Create the FROM
Root<PubThread> rootPubThread = mainQuery.from(PubThread.class);
// Create the JOIN from the first select: join-chaining. You only need the return for ordering. e.g. cq.orderBy(cb.asc(categoryJoin.get(Pub_.title)));
Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoin = rootPubThread.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
// Create the WHERE
mainQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)));
// Create the SELECT, at last
mainQuery.select(rootPubThread).distinct(true);

// 2) Subquery
Subquery<PubThread> subquery = mainQuery.subquery(PubThread.class); 
Root<PubThread> rootPubThreadSub = subquery.from(PubThread.class); 
//subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId));
Join<Pub, PubCategory> categoryJoinSub = rootPubThreadSub.join(PubThread_.pups).join(Pub_.pubCategory);
subquery.select(rootPubThreadSub);

//Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(
        //criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread),
        criteriaBuilder.equal(categoryJoinSub.get(PubCategory_.id), categoryJoin.get(PubCategory_.id)),

        criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)
        );
subquery.where(correlatePredicate);     

//Predicate correlatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThreadSub.get(PubThread_.id), rootPubThread);
Predicate mainPredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(
        criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPubThread.get(PubThread_.id), threadId)),
        criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery)
        );
//cq.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));
mainQuery.where(mainPredicate);


TypedQuery<PubThread> typedQuery = em.createQuery(mainQuery);
List<PubThread> otherPubThreads = typedQuery.getResultList();
```